# How to replace a foreign key by another field in swing with jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, foreign-keys

This is a beginner question, maybe I'm missing something obvious, but how should I use a `TableModel` with `jdbc` in order to show another field's value from the referenced table instead of a foreign key's value?

Two possible solutions come to my mind, but I'm not very happy with them. (Here they come but please note that I'm not insisting that my ideas should be addressed in the answer if there is a better solution.)

One is doing queries on the referenced table to get the substitute value for each foreign-key field value in `getValueAt`. This doesn't seem too efficient (even if cached) and I wonder how should I synchronize this with editing and writing changed data back to the table.

The other one is replacing the value of the field in/with the SQL query. This won't make updating/inserting too straightforward but it could be advanced further to use a view. Seems like a working solution but do I really need to alter my database just for using it with a simple java application?

Are there any better solutions / is there something wrong with these / am I plain wrong? :)

Should support reading, updating, inserting, dropping. I'm using mysql (and/or sqlite).

Comment: Is there a term for "show another field's value from the referenced table instead of a foreign key's value"? :)

Comment: We can infer you have an RDBMS and that what you want to do is write a select query with a join. If you use JPA you could use an eager fetch to do it for you, but that's another story. Try writing some sql to get what you want, then add the Java/Table/etc later.

Comment: @Romski I actually have a select query with join what just gets me what I want. But if the user edits the values in the table, how do I update these values back? Do I have to mirror the complexity inherent in the select-join query, with java code in `setValueAt` (+1 statement per foreign key I suppose)? Thanks for suggesting JPA, but I want to try it with jdbc for now.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to translate the user data back to your database model. Since you are using jdbc, that means building the SQL. You should look at PreparedStatement, see the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for usage. I expect you will be basing this action on some event, such as a save button, or value changed.